# Publish single project from Azure Dev Ops to Azure App Service Environment

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-devops, continuous-integration, publish

We have a App Service Enviroment https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/intro I have set up an App in but I am struggling to either publish from my machine (I've added the URLs to my HOSTS file and I can see it in a browser) and cant see a clear way to publish it from Azure Dev Ops (my preferred option).

I'd be happy to be pointed to TFM but everything I find is out of date / not near the options I can see in Dev Ios or Visual Studio (2019 / 2019 Preview).

EDIT: Also note this is a multi project solution (various console apps, an API and a website it is the API / Website I want to publish)

EDIT 2: So "its always DNS" it was a DNS issue in trying to publish from Visual Studio

Comment: For clarity when I publish from Visual Studio I receive this message


 Could not connect to the remote computer ("APPSERVICENAME.appserviceenvironment.net"). Make sure that the remote computer name is correct and that you are able to connect to that computer.  Learn more at: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_INVALID.
The remote name could not be resolved: 'APPSERVICENAME.appserviceenvironment.net'

where APPSERVICENAME is the name of the App Service environment I have set up and can browse to

Answer (score 0):

You can check these two links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/quickstart-deploy-to-azure?view=vs-2019

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment?tabs=github

Comment: Thanks @Jesús Hernández I had tried the first which led to the comment "publish from my machine" even though I have added the endpoint to my HOSTs file and I can browse to it. Visual Studio says it can't see / publish there

The second doesn't work as when you choose Azure Pipelines it sends me to Dev Ops but will not allow me to choose an existing organisation / Project (I have access to lots of each)  and instead wants me to create a new Org / Project

Comment: If you already have an organisation in Azure DevOps, for example where your git repository exists, you can create a pipeline right away. Just look for Azure App Service in the options presented for you and connect it to your resource in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Visual Studio, see: [Deploy an ASP.NET Web App in Azure App Service](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vsts/appservice/).

If you use Azure pipeline, this doc: [Deploy an Azure Web App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/webapp?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic) provides a tutorial to build web app and then deploy to an Azure Web App. Also see this video for detailed guidance: [Build and deploy to an Azure Web App using VSTS (Quick Starts)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9NT_dG_0qLo).

BTW, there are a few useful tools: [Azure DevOps Labs](https://azuredevopslabs.com/), [Azure DevOps Services Demo Generator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/demo-gen/?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts), and [DevOps Starter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops-project/overview#devops-starter-and-azure-devops-integration) which will help you to get started with Azure DevOps services to automate software delivery and meet business needs.

Comment: Thanks @Edward Han-MSFT I will give those a go, although as I said the issues I am having I think are specific to ASE rather than just publishing from Visual Studio / Dev Ops to Azure App Service both of which I have done before

Comment: Yes as I thought @Edward Han-MSFT the youtube video is not pertinent to my issue / doesnt work and the others suggest I want to start from scratch. I have an existing multi project solution I need to publish to Azure App Service under an App Service Environment